# ActiveRecord: Can successfully query with .where(foo: "bar") but .where.not(foo: "bar") doesn't return the correct results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a query built like so:

```
@events = current_organization.events.order(started_at: :asc)
```

I would like query all those events where the `status` is not `"canceled"`. However, when I use a query like this:

```
current_organization.events.order(started_at: :asc).where.not(status: "canceled")
```

It returns nothing. However, just for experimentations sake I tried:

```
@events = current_organization.events.where(status: "canceled")
```

It successfully returned the canceled events. For some reason the inverse does not work. Is there any reason why that is?

Edit: My only work around I can find is just using `where(status: nil)` but that's really unintuitive.

Comment: Try checking the #to_sql output.  This is helpful for debugging sql statements

current_organization.events.order(started_at: :asc).where.not(status: "canceled").to_sql

Comment: Do you have a `default_scope` set on your events model?

Comment: @MickeySheu, Here are the different outputs

`@events = current_organization.events.order(started_at: :asc).where(status: "canceled").to_sql`

`=> "SELECT \"events\".* FROM \"events\" WHERE \"events\".\"organization_id\" = 1 AND \"events\".\"status\" = 'canceled' ORDER BY \"events\".\"started_at\" ASC”`

`@events = current_organization.events.order(started_at: :asc).where.not(status: "canceled").to_sql`

`=> “SELECT \"events\".* FROM \"events\" WHERE \"events\".\"organization_id\" = 1 AND (\"events\".\"status\" != 'canceled') ORDER BY \"events\".\"started_at\" ASC”`

Comment: @mysmallidea, no default scope set on my events model

Comment: Why are you expecting your `where.not` query to find anything? Are you sure there are non-canceled events for that organization?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, there are exactly two events where `status: "canceled"` I am in a testing environment with only 10 events. If I use `.where(status: "canceled")` I get the two events. But I cannot use the inverse to omit the two events from the rest of the events.

Comment: Just for sanity's sake you include the result of `.events.all.select { |c| c.status != "canceled" }.count`? Seems like both your original code and the answer should work.

Comment: @maxple,

`current_organization.events.all.select { |c| c.status != "canceled" }.count
  Event Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 1]]
=> 6`

Bonus is the inverse:

`current_organization.events.all.select { |c| c.status = "canceled" }.count
  Event Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 1]]
=> 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This update to your question:

> Edit: My only work around I can find is just using `where(status: nil)` but that's really unintuitive.

is important. That tells me that your `status` column allows `NULL` values and that you have `NULL` values.

Those `NULL`s combined with ActiveRecord's somewhat poor implementation of `where.not` is the cause of your trouble. If we look at the SQL that is produced by:

```
where.not(status: "canceled")
```

we see:

```
("events"."status" != 'canceled')
```

But in SQL, both `x = null` and `x <> null` both evaluate to `null` for all `x` (including when `x` itself is `null`) and `null` is not a truthy value in SQL; that means that `x <> y` is not exactly the opposite of `x = y` when `null`s are involved: if a row's `status` is `null` then neither `where status = 'canceled'` nor `where status != 'canceled'` will find it.

Whenever `null`s are involved, you have to work with operators that treat `null` they way you expect: `is null`, `is not null`, `is distinct from`, `is not distinct from`, ...

Allowing `null`s in your `status` column sounds odd to me and fixing that would make the problem go away:

1. Add a migration to change all the `null` statuses to something nicer to work with. A `status is null` column says that the row/model has no status at all and that's odd so give them all a real status code.
2. Add a migration to make your `status` column `not null` so that you'll never have to worry about `null` statuses again.
3. Update your model's validations to not allow `status.nil?` to happen.

In general, don't use nullable columns anywhere unless you're certain that the `null`s make sense and you're prepared to deal with how `null` works in SQL.

Comment: Would setting a default value to my column be the same as making the column not null?

Comment: Not really but you could set it to `not null` and add the default. You really do want the column to be `not null` though, otherwise `null`s will end up in there and cause problems.

Comment: Your answer was really good at explaining how SQL handles null. I went ahead and made the necessary changes to that column and I don't think it will give me a problem from here on out. Thank you.